# What's wrong with my Backpropagation algorithm implementation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I tried to implement a no-hidden-layer neural network to hack with MNIST dataset.

I used sigmoid as activate function and cross-entropy as loss function.

For simplicity I my network has no hidden layer, just input and output.

```
X = trainImage
label = trainLabel

w1 = np.random.normal(np.zeros([28 * 28, 10]))
b1 = np.random.normal(np.zeros([10]))

def sigm(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def acc():
    y = sigm(np.matmul(X, w1))
    return sum(np.argmax(label, 1) == np.argmax(y, 1)) / y.shape[0]

def loss():
    y = sigm(np.matmul(X, w1))
    return sum((-label * np.log(y)).flatten())

a = np.matmul(X[0:1], w1)

y = sigm(a)

dy = - label[0:1] / y

ds = dy * y * (1 - y)

dw = np.matmul(X[0:1].transpose(), ds)

db = ds

def bp(lr, i):
    global w1, b1, a, y, dy, ds, dw, db
    a = np.matmul(X[i:i+1], w1)
    y = sigm(a)
    dy = - label[0:1] / y
    ds = dy * y * (1 - y)
    dw = np.matmul(X[i:i+1].transpose(), ds)
    db = ds
    w1 = w1 - lr * dw
    b1 = b1 - lr * db

for i in range(100 * 60000):
    bp(1, i % 60000)
    if i % 60000 == 0:
        print("#", int(i / 60000), "loss:", loss(), "acc:", acc())
```

This is the part of my implementation of backpropagation algorithm, but it doesn't work as expected. The descent of loss function is extremely slow (I tried with learning rate varing from 0.001 to 1), and the accuracy never grows over than 0.1.

The output is like this:

```
# 0 loss: 279788.368245 acc: 0.0903333333333
# 1 loss: 279788.355211 acc: 0.09035
# 2 loss: 279788.350629 acc: 0.09035
# 3 loss: 279788.348228 acc: 0.09035
# 4 loss: 279788.346736 acc: 0.09035
# 5 loss: 279788.345715 acc: 0.09035
# 6 loss: 279788.344969 acc: 0.09035
# 7 loss: 279788.3444 acc: 0.09035
# 8 loss: 279788.343951 acc: 0.09035
# 9 loss: 279788.343587 acc: 0.09035
# 10 loss: 279788.343286 acc: 0.09035
# 11 loss: 279788.343033 acc: 0.09035
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here, there are a few possible factors that are preventing this from working.

Firstly, you have to randomly initialize your weights and biases. From what I am seeing, you are trying to change a value that doesn't yet have a tangible value(ex: `w1 = 0`).

Secondly, your optimizer is not suited for the MNIST dataset. The optimizer is what changes the values based on the backpropagation, so it is very important that you choose the right optimizer. Gradient Descent is better suited for this dataset, and from what I can see, you are not using Gradient Descent. If you are attempting to make a Gradient Descent optimizer with your code, you are most likely doing it wrong. Gradient Descent involves partial derivatives of the SSE (Sum of Squared Error), which I do not see in this code.

If you want to go with the Gradient Descent optimizer, you will have to make a few changes to your code besides implementing the mathematics behind Gradient Descent. You will have to use ReLU activation function(which I suggest you do anyway) instead of the sigmoid function. This will make sure the Vanishing Gradient problem doesn't occur. Also, your should make your loss function the reduced mean of the cross entropy. The optimizer will be much more effective this way.

Hope this helps.